# Get last comments created

Tags: ruby-on-rails

There are Articles and Comments.

**The goal**: list all comments that are posted last on all articles.

For example:

> Article #1 has 3 comments
>
> Article #2 has 1 comment
>
> Article #3 has no comments
>
> ---
>
> goal: Get 2 comments that are created last on Article #1, #2

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :article, counter_cache: true

 def self.last_comment
   # list all comments which are created last on any article
 end
end


class CommentsController < ApplicationController

def last_comments
  @last_comments = Comment.last_comment
end

end
```

Comment: When you post your code, it helps to post something substantive, rather than just a skeleton.

Answer (score 1):

The following would do your work but it doesn't seem to me a good solution:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
  def last_comment
    comments.last
  end
end


class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :article, counter_cache: true

 def self.last_comment
   Article.all.each_with_object([]) { |a, last_comments| last_comments << a.last_comment }
 end
end
```

Now you can get all last comments:

```
Comment.last_comment
```

And last comment of specific article:

```
@article.last_comment
```

Comment: This would work, but this would also load all Articles in to memory every time the pseudoscope is called.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to cache `last_comment_id` on Article.

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, after_add: :update_last_comment, after_remove: :update_last_comment
  has_one :last_comment, class_name: "Comment"

  private

  # could process this as an asynchronous job
  def update_last_comment
    self.last_comment = comments.order(created_at: :desc).first
    self.save!
  end
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :article, counter_cache: true

  def self.last_comment
    joins(:article).
      where("id = articles.last_comment_id")
  end
end
```

The `after_add`/`after_remove` are ActiveRecord Association Callbacks, documented [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html%23association-callbacks).

Comment: Replace `order(created_at: :desc)` with `order("comments.created_at DESC")` in Rails 3.